# Users login not working, showing error "incorrect username or password"

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have **UsersController** i'm trying to login using email and password fields, i'm also using Password Hashing, also my password field is of text datatype. which is working fine, but i'm unable to login, showing me an error

> username or password is incorrect

`UsersController.php`

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user)
            {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
        }

    }
```

`AppController.php`

```
   public function initialize()
        {
            parent::initialize();
            $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
            $this->loadComponent('Flash');
            $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
                'authenticate'=>[
                    'Form'=>[
                        'fields'=>[
                            'username'=>'email',
                            'password'=>'password'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],

                'loginRedirect'=>[
                    'controller'=>'Users',
                    'action'=>'index'
                ],

                'loginAction'=>[
                    'controller'=>'Users',
                    'action'=>'login'
                ]
            ]);
             $this->Auth->allow(['add']);
}
```

`login.ctp`

```
<h1>Login</h1>

<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('email') ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

UsersTable

```
id char(100)
name varchar(100)
email varchar(100)
password (text)
```

Comment: What is the name of the table in which you save password and email of the user?

Comment: Its UsersTable, i didn't make it manually, i used baking.

Answer (score 0):

Please add password hasher at your Entity Class( scr/Model/Entity/User.php )

```
    use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;    
    protected function _setPassword($password)
        {
            if (strlen($password) > 0) {
              return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
            }
        }
```

After adding this, make a new user then try to login from newly created user.

I did this which is working here

UsersController.php

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user)
        {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
    }

}

public function logout()
{
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

AppController.php

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth',[
            'authenticate'=>[
                'Form'=>[
                    'fields'=>[
                        'username'=>'email',
                        'password'=>'password'
                    ]                        
                ]
            ],

            'loginRedirect'=>[
                'controller'=>'Users',
                'action'=>'index'
            ],

            'loginAction'=>[
                'controller'=>'Users',
                'action'=>'login'
            ]
        ]);
         $this->Auth->allow(['add']);
```

User.php [Entity]

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    if (strlen($password) > 0) {
      return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

login.ctp

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('email') ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

If do not work the above code for you, you can try adding this at your AppController

```
'fields'=>[ 'username'=>'email', 'password'=>'password' ], 
'userModel' => 'Users'
```